# I am a definite compulsion to some. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am a definite compulsion to some,
>
> Something to which not all will succumb.
>
> A grey above an orange, blue or green,
>
> Thought in some circles, to be obscene.
>
> A magician disappears in a cloud of me,
>
> And then, no longer, him you will see.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> Smoke

I am a definite compulsion to some,

> Smoking is an addiction for some

Something to which not all will succumb.

> Not everybody takes up smoking

A grey above an orange,

> Smoke is grey usually above an orange flame.

blue

> [Smoke on the water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_on_the_Water)

or green,

> [Prairie smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prairie_smoke). 
>  Also possibly refers to menthol cigarettes, as pointed out by Meta45 in comments

Thought in some circles, to be obscene.

> Smoking is often seen as a bad or disgusting habit.

A magician disappears in a cloud of me,

> A magician disappears in a cloud of smoke.

And then, no longer, him you will see.

Comment: Smoke is grey for the third hint?

Comment: the colors might point to the type of sigaret. e.g. green or blue is menthol.